# how do i put an excel row into a list

Tags: excel, python-2.7, list, row

I have an excel sheet with parameters that I am trying to export into a text pad.

```
site name    site      site1     site2     site2
host       hostname  hostname1 hostname2 hostname2
ip          x.x.x.x    x.x.x.x  x.x.x.x   x.x.x.x
sh#             1          1        1         2
ILAN in       yes         yes      no        no
ilan out       no          no      no        no
```

What I am wanting is to take the info for each site/host and put into a text pad as, one text pad per hostname. in this example there are 4 hosts, so 4 text pads.

text pad name site-hostname-SH# and in the text pad:

```
host = hostname
ip = x.x.x.x 
SH# = 1 or 2
ILAN IN = yes or no
ILAN out = yes or no
```

I am able to find the keyword such as host, but unable to put that row into a list. I am using the text pad(s) as global variables for another script. The excel is where the information comes from and my other script telnets into the equipment to provision it. Right now I have to manually change all of the variables for each shelf and want to automate the variables from the excel sheet.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import sys
import warnings

if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
#opens filechooser for excel workbook
Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print ("Working, please be patient")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

#lists worksheets in workbook to pick which worksheet to import
print ("\r")
count = 0
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    tlist = ws.title
    print count,tlist
    count = count + 1

x = input ("\nchoose number:\n")
ws = wb.worksheets[x]
print (ws)

#will eventually put into a function
#finds keyword, in this case site name
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        try:
            if cell.value == "Site Name":
                print ("yes")
                print ("TRUE")
                print cell.row, cell.column
                row = cell.row
                column = cell.column
                print column

                site = ws.cell(row = row, column = column)
                print ("this is: %s" %(site.value) )

                print ("this is row %s" %row)
                print row
                print column
        except (AttributeError):
            continue

have tried:
#print ("this is row: %s" %(row) )
##print(row)
#print (SiteName[1])

##x = ws.max_row + 1
##x = int(row)
##for r in range(x, column + 1):
##    d=ws.cell(row=x,column=r)
##    print(d.value)
##print ("this is the row number: %s" %(row) )
##print str(row)
##print ("this is: %s" %(site.value) )
##for i in range(row, col + 1): 
##    cell_obj = ws.cell(row = row, column = i) 
##    print(cell_obj.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    keyword = row[0].value
    values = [item.value for item in row[1:]]
    if keyword == 'site name':
        print(keyword)
        print(values)
        print('-----\n')
        # do whatever you want here
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did try the code and it does not put the rows into an iterable list. How would I search for the keywords instead of having it print out every row? Instead of printing every row, just the rows that I want?

Comment: @James I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can filter out the rows using the `keyword` with something like `if keyword == 'site name': ...`, right?

Comment: Thank you for the help.. Tried pasting in my final code, but could not figure out how to format.